# Getting error while trying to run the node

Tags: pokt

When I am running the `pocket start` command, I am getting the following error:

```
invalid chains.json: unexpected end of JSON input
```

When I run the command to check node status `curl http://localhost:26657/status`, it is telling me `catching_up: false` so not sure now if node is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your node is running, however you have either not provided a `chains.json` in your datadir or the file is not a valid json file. Your `chains.json` lives in your `<datadir>/config` directory.

Here's an example of how to set it up: https://docs.pokt.network/core/guides/quickstart#chains-json